# Triangle Strip artifacts

Tags: three.js

I'm playing with draw groups in `THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode` draw mode, and I'm seeing some odd artifacts. I think it might be a bug, but I'd like someone else to confirm that I'm not doing something wrong before submitting a report.

In the snippet below, I create 4 squares composed of 4 triangles each. They're all indexed for right-hand rendering. (I realize that triangle strips don't technically need indexing, but I could potentially have complex shapes with re-used vertices.) Their other properties and results are as follows:

**Red Square**

- Two groups: 0-9 and 9-12
- Standard front-side rendering
- Black artifact on the back-face of triangle index 1

**Green Square**

- One group: 0-12
- Standard front-side rendering
- Black artifacts on the back-face of triangles index 1 & 3
- **The same thing happens when I don't use grouping at all**

**Blue Square**

- Two groups: 0-9 and 9-12
- Double-side rendering
- Renders as expected

**Yellow Square**

- One group: 0-12
- Double-side rendering
- Triangle index 3 renders black on both sides

So did I miss something, or should I submit this as a bug in three.js?

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls, stats;

var WIDTH = window.innerWidth,
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight,
 FOV = 35,
 NEAR = 1,
 FAR = 1000;

function createShapes(){
 var bg = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
 bg.addAttribute("position", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
  -1, 1, 0,
  -1, -1, 0,
  0, 1, 0,
  0, -1, 0,
  1, 1, 0,
  1, -1, 0
 ]), 3));
 bg.addAttribute("normal", new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array([
  0, 0, 1,
  0, 0, 1,
  0, 0, 1,
  0, 0, 1,
  0, 0, 1,
  0, 0, 1
 ]), 3));
 bg.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint32Array([
  0, 1, 2,
  3, 2, 1,
  2, 3, 4,
  5, 4, 3
 ]), 1));

 var group1 = bg.clone(),
  group2 = bg.clone(),
  group3 = bg.clone(),
  group4 = bg.clone();

 /**/
 group1.clearGroups();
 group1.addGroup(0, 9, 0);
 group1.addGroup(9, 3, 0);

 group2.clearGroups();
 group2.addGroup(0, 12, 0);

 group3.clearGroups();
 group3.addGroup(0, 9, 0);
 group3.addGroup(9, 3, 0);

 group4.clearGroups();
 group4.addGroup(0, 12, 0);
 /**/

 var mat1 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: "red"}),
  mat2 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: "green"}),
  mat3 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: "blue", side: THREE.DoubleSide}),
  mat4 = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: "yellow", side: THREE.DoubleSide});

 var m1 = new THREE.Mesh(group1, [mat1]),
  m2 = new THREE.Mesh(group2, [mat2]),
  m3 = new THREE.Mesh(group3, [mat3]),
  m4 = new THREE.Mesh(group4, [mat4]);

 m1.drawMode = THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode;
 m2.drawMode = THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode;
 m3.drawMode = THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode;
 m4.drawMode = THREE.TriangleStripDrawMode;

 m1.position.set(-2, 2, 0);
 m2.position.set(2, 2, 0);
 m3.position.set(-2, -2, 0);
 m4.position.set(2, -2, 0);

 scene.add(m1, m2, m3, m4);
}

function init() {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "slateGray";

 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });

 document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
 document.body.style.margin = "0";
 document.body.style.padding = "0";

 scene = new THREE.Scene();

 camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(FOV, WIDTH / HEIGHT, NEAR, FAR);
 camera.position.z = 20;
 scene.add(camera);

 controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
 controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.5;
 controls.rotateSpeed = 3;

 var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, Infinity);
 camera.add(light);

 stats = new Stats();
 stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
 stats.domElement.style.top = '0';
 document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);

 resize();
 window.onresize = resize;

 // POPULATE EXAMPLE
 createShapes();

 animate();
}

function resize() {
 WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
 HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
 if (renderer && camera && controls) {
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  camera.aspect = WIDTH / HEIGHT;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  controls.handleResize();
 }
}

function render() {
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function animate() {
 requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 render();
 controls.update();
 stats.update();
}

function threeReady() {
 init();
}

(function () {
 function addScript(url, callback) {
  callback = callback || function () { };
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.addEventListener("load", callback);
  script.setAttribute("src", url);
  document.head.appendChild(script);
 }

 addScript("https://threejs.org/build/three.js", function () {
  addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js", function () {
   addScript("https://threejs.org/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js", function () {
    threeReady();
   })
  })
 })
})();
```

r86 (the problem has actually been around for a while)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an "AHA!" moment while looking at some other examples. My indexing was off, which is also throwing off my grouping.

The indexing should be:

```
bg.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint32Array([
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
]), 1));
```

Which makes sense, because that's how the triangle strip defines the steps of its vertices.

Then to draw a full square, I needed a single group:

```
group1.addGroup(0, 6, 0);
```

Which means start at the group index of 0, for 6 group indices (which covers all of them).

There's still a problem when trying to render an (odd index) individual triangle. Because the winding order for odd triangles is backwards, creating a group that starts with an odd triangle will not be lit correctly (renders black). But that's for another question...